# Slackbot api can't receive messages

Tags: node.js, bots, slack-api

I'm building a SlackBot with NodeJS.

I'm currently using this library [slackbots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slackbots), but the problem is that after the initialization, the bot does not appear in the Apps category, but it's inside SlackBot and every time I type a message it returns an error message:

```
I'm sorry, I don't understand! Sometimes I have an easier time with a few simple keywords. Or you can head to our wonderful Help Center for more assistance!
```

[image]

On the other side, when I send a message to a user I can see the bot I have set up:
[image]

How can I make the bot Hugo separated from the SlackBot inside Slack?

That's how I set it up:

```
 var SlackBot                = require('slackbots');

 var bot = new SlackBot({
      token: process.env.SLACK_TOKEN,
      name: 'Hugo'
  });

  function get() {
      return bot;
  }

  exports.get = function() {
      return bot;
  }

  exports.send_message = function(user_ref, message) {
      bot.postMessage(user_ref, message).then((data) => {
          return data;
      });
  }

  exports.get_users = function() {
      var user_list = get().getUsers();
      return user_list;
  }
```

And this is how I send the test message:

```
  var bot                     = require('./modules/bot.js');

  bot.get().on('message', function(data) {
      console.log("#######################################"); // -> debug only
      console.log(data);
      console.log("#######################################");

      bot.send_message('USER_ID', 'test response');
  });
```